# If I move a number from memory to a register, will it be placed in the same order?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, cpu-registers

Assume I have the following number in memory: `01 00 00 00`.
If I moved it into eax, will it be placed in the same order: `01 00 00 00`?

And so `ax` will contain `01 00`? If this is the case does that mean that a register treats "the first byte on the left" as the least significant byte, while it treats "the first byte on the right" (`al` in case of `eax`) as the most significant byte? So this is kind of like little endian! (and I know that registers don't have the notion of endianness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when you load the number into the register, they are effectively reversed. Registers doesn't have endianness, as you say, but if you display the number in the register it will be reverse of the way that the memory content is displayed.

Loading `01 00 00 00` into `eax` will give you the number `00000001`. The content of `ax` will be `0001`, the content of `ah` will be `00` and the content of `al` will be `01`.

Comment: You mean the content of `ax` will be `0000`? If I move a number from a register to memory, it will also be reversed right?

Comment: @mahmoud_t1: No, I mean that the content of `ax` will be `0001`, it's the lower 16 bits of `eax`. Yes, moving in the other direction will reverse the data in the same manner.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mixed up the names (I thought that `ax` is the name of the higher 16 bits of `eax`).

Comment: Just keep this in mind: In little endian format the least sigificant Byte will be saved at the lowest address in memory. When you store the number 11 44 05 in memory, the low 05 will be stored at "address" (for example: 0xbfafd421), the middle 44 will be stored at "address+1" (e.g. 0xbfafd422) while the 11 will be stored at "address+2" (e.g. 0xbfafd423). In big endian the 01 would have been stored at "address" instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define what -endian is some memory there are several needed conditions:

1. There must be memory, divided by cells.
2. The number written in the memory must occupy several cells.
3. The memory cells must have addresses.

Let see how the registers are related to these conditions (I will write about 32bit x86 architecture):

1. Yes the registers are memory, but are they dividable? Yes, they are memory and they are dividable.
2. The number can occupy several cells - for example 12345678h, in EAX occupies: al=78h, ah=56h, the remaining of EAX contains 1234h
3. Are these memory cells addressable? No they are not. There is no addresses of al, ah, ax and the not named part of eax. We can't say what register has bigger address and what smaller. That is why the registers does not have endianness.